# Find $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(e^{2\pi i/6},e^{2\pi i / 10}) / \mathbb{Q})$

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials, galois-extensions

First I need to show that the extension $\mathbb{Q}(e^{2\pi i/6},e^{2\pi i / 10}) / \mathbb{Q}$ is actually Galois extension, and then I need to find the group itself.

Denote $\alpha = e^{2\pi i/6} $, $\beta = e^{2\pi i / 10}$.

I guess the first step is to find the minimal polynomial of $\alpha,\beta$, but I'm not really sure how to do it. I know that the following polynomials are zeroed by $\alpha, \beta$:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{29} x^i,\quad (\sum_{i=0}^5 x^i) \cdot (\sum_{i=0}^9 x^i)$$

Both are reducible, but I don't know how can I reduce them further.

Comment: Hint 1: $\alpha^3 = -1$ and $\beta^5 = -1$.\
Hint 2: Since $\alpha, \beta \notin \mathbb{R}$ the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is $\mu_\alpha(X) = X^2-X+1$ and the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ is $\mu_\beta(X) = X^4-X^3+X^2-X+1$. To see that $\mu_\beta$ is indeed irreducible note that $\mu_\beta(-X) = \phi_5(X)$.

Comment: **Hint:** Show: $$\mathbb Q(\alpha,\beta)=\mathbb Q\left(e^{2\pi i/30}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: This answer uses cyclotomic field theory.

Let $K_n$ denote the $n$<sup>th</sup> cyclotomic field.

Then your field extension is $K_6 K_{10}$ (compositum).

Then $K_6 K_{10} = K_{\operatorname{lcm}(6,10)} = K_{30}$, so its Galois group is $(\Bbb Z/30\Bbb Z)^\times$.